# operand should contain 1 column(s) or syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have to do a query to insert data in a table, selecting some field from another table and I have this error: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

the query is the following:

```
INSERT into lezione  
(data, ora, punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, puntiAssenzaTempo,  
 puntiDisdettaTempo, orarioDisdetta, note, puntiAssenzaPunti, puntiDisdettaPunti,        special) 
values (str_to_date('17-02-2014', '%d-%m-%Y'), 
(SELECT punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, puntiAssenzaTempo,  
puntiDisdettaTempo, orarioDisdetta, note, puntiAssenzaPunti, puntiDisdettaPunti,  special 
FROM SettimanaTipo where giornoSettimana = 1))
```

Searching on the web I learn that the SELECT clause doen't want the parenthesis so I removed them and the query is the following

```
INSERT into lezione  
(data, ora, punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, puntiAssenzaTempo,  
 puntiDisdettaTempo, orarioDisdetta, note, puntiAssenzaPunti, puntiDisdettaPunti,        special) 
values (str_to_date('17-02-2014', '%d-%m-%Y'), 
SELECT punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, puntiAssenzaTempo,  
puntiDisdettaTempo, orarioDisdetta, note, puntiAssenzaPunti, puntiDisdettaPunti,  special 
FROM SettimanaTipo where giornoSettimana = 1)
```

but now the error is this: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, puntiAssenzaTempo,  puntiDisdettaTempo,' at line 4 0.001 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following query instead :

```
INSERT into lezione  
(      data, ora, punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, puntiAssenzaTempo,  
       puntiDisdettaTempo, orarioDisdetta, note, puntiAssenzaPunti, 
       puntiDisdettaPunti, special)  

SELECT str_to_date('17-02-2014', '%d-%m-%Y'), punti, istruttore, bike, riserve, 
       puntiAssenzaTempo, puntiDisdettaTempo, orarioDisdetta, note, puntiAssenzaPunti, 
       puntiDisdettaPunti, special 
FROM SettimanaTipo WHERE giornoSettimana = 1
```

Also you have one problem there are `12` columns in `insert` clause while you are providing only `11` columns, this is the reason you are getting error 1 => `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.